# How can I check which fields are giving errors with a Status 500 response from an Ajax call?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am performing an Ajax submit ASP.Net **with MVC**:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
        action,
        "References",
        null,
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            UpdateTargetId = "update-message",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            OnSuccess = success,
            OnFailure = "ajaxOnFailure"
        }, new { @id = "dialogForm", @class = "ui-widget dialog-admin" }))
```

Which is converted to:

```
<form method="post" id="dialogForm" data-ajax-update="#update-message"
 data-ajax-success="menuDialogSuccess('Create Complete','Create')" 
data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-method="POST" 
data-ajax="true" class="ui-widget dialog-admin" 
action="/Administration/Menus/Create" novalidate="novalidate">
```

This replies with a status 500 web page with the following:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'
```

I cannot see what field this refers to. Is there some place I can look to track this down?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out that the problem is caused by this:

```
    [StringLength(3, ErrorMessage="Order must be 3 characters")]
    [Range(0, 99, ErrorMessage = "{0} must be between {1} and {2}")]
    [DisplayName("Order")]
    public int Order { get; set; }
```

The code is trying to get the length of something that is not a string.

Answer (score 1):

It looks from code that your action expects `ID` parameter of type `int`, while you are sending 
it a string `"dialogForm"`. Change your action parameter `ID`  to `string`.

Comment: The ID / dialogID is common code used in many places so I believe it is not this. The code seems to be generated by MVC#. I just don't understand where.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use firebug addon to track down the error location.

Comment: This is using MVC. I believe the error is coming from some MVC code but I am not sure where. Not sure how I can use firebug. The error is being generated by c# MVC code.